# drop down list referencing multiple data tables

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, datatable

I'm creating a WMI program that outputs the query to a data table and then to a data grid. I want to create a history drop down list that would put the current date and time as an item and clone the data table that was just created to it as a "value".

Selecting the items in the drop down list would change the data grid to whatever previous data table that was ran at that time.

Here's the code so far but I'm not sure how to add the data table as a string or maybe an array ?

```
// copy current data table

DataTable cloneTable = new DataTable();
cloneTable = dt.Copy();

ddlEventhistory.Items.Add(new Data { 
    Name = DateTime.Now.ToString(), 
    Value = cloneTable () 
}); 
ddlEventhistory.DisplayMember = "Name";
ddlEventhistory.ValueMember = "Value";
```

**Update 1:** Here is my custom class:

```
 private class Data 
 { 
     public string Name { get; set; } 
     public Object Value { get; set; } 
 }
```

**Update 2:** Here is what happens my drop down list is changed:

```
private void ddlEventhistory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgEvent.DataSource = (ddlEventhistory.SelectedValue as Data).Value as DataTable;                 
}
```

**Update 3:** Here is the final code

```
private class Data 
 { 
     public string Name { get; set; } 
     public Object Value { get; set; } 
 }

//History

        //take existing data table and copy it's source
        DataTable eventhistory = new DataTable();
        eventhistory = (DataTable)dgEvent.DataSource;

        ddlEventhistory.Items.Add(new Data { Name = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Value = eventhistory });
        ddlEventhistory.DisplayMember = "Name";
        ddlEventhistory.ValueMember = "Value";

//when drop down list selection is changed do....

private void ddlEventhistory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Assign DataTable of selected ComboBox item to DataGrid.
       dgEvent.DataSource = (ddlEventhistory.SelectedItem as Data).Value as DataTable;
    }
```

Comment: 1. `new DataTable();` is not needed if you assign a new object from `dt.Clone()`, 2. What is ddlEventHistory (assuming a datagrid)?

Comment: ddlEventHistory is my dropdownlist name, i have the new there so it will create a new clone each time the search completes ( i'm using a background worker and its in runworkercompleted )

Comment: You are adding an instance of `Data` to your dropdownlist. Is that a custom class? If so, what is the data type of the Value property? If it is object, couldn't you just assign cloneTable to it directly?

Comment: Yes it is a custom class i tried assigning it as an object and datatable but when i try to send my datagrid's data source it just comes up blank. this is the code im using when a user changes the list.


`private void ddlEventhistory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           


            dgEvent.DataSource = ddlEventhistory.SelectedValue;
            
        }`

dgEvent is my datagrid name. Thank you for your help so far !

Comment: Assigning `SelectedValue` to `dgEvent.DataSource` will not work because its value is an instance of `Data` and `DataSource` needs something that implements `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource` like `DataTable`. You might try `dgEvent.DataSource = (ddlEventhistory.SelectedValue as Data).Value as DataTable;`. This statement sets your `DataTable` as the `DataSource`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code but I'm getting a nullrereferenceexception was unhandled, object reference not set to an instance of an object. I think the data table is not getting copied leaving the table blank and throwing this exception. 

according to MSDN link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx[link] Clone creates a new DataTable with the same structure as the original DataTable, but does not copy any data (the new DataTable will not contain any DataRows). To copy both the structure and data into a new DataTable, use Copy.

Comment: You are using System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList? Also, could you post the code for your Data class?

Comment: I'm using System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox with the dropdownstyle set to dropdownlist. I also updated my original post above with the custom class if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a copy of your data to your Combobox items like this.

```
//copy current data table
DataTable cloneTable = dt.Copy();

ddlEventhistory.Items.Add(new Data { Name = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Value = cloneTable }); 
ddlEventhistory.DisplayMember = "Name";
ddlEventhistory.ValueMember = "Value";
```

And then when a user selects one of those items you can display it in a DataGrid like this.

```
private void ddlEventhistory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assign DataTable of selected ComboBox item to DataGrid.
    dgEvent.DataSource = (ddlEventhistory.SelectedItem as Data).Value as DataTable;
}
```

Comment: I tried that code but it still does not work but, the exception error is gone now. The datagrid just dissapears leaving just the grid control itself with no table in it when I select a history from the ddlEventhistory. I am using a backgroudnd worker and the copy data table code above is used in the runworkercompleted event if that helps. Any other suggestions ? Thanks!

Comment: got it working !, i had to add this line `DataTable eventhistory = new DataTable();
            eventhistory = (DataTable)dgEvent.DataSource;` Ill mark your answer and update the final code i used. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Wow, this is kinda tricky. Apparently SelectedValue will be null [unless you are using DataBinding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2006/11/07/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat.aspx) to populate your DataGrid. I have updated the answer to reflect this requirement.